# What modification need to be made to the jquery plugin boilerplate to compile in typescript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, typescript

In the [jQuery plugin boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/) there is some great starting code for jQuery plugin development, but copying and pasting that code into a typescript and compiling causes the compilation to fail.

The error comes from the `undefined` argument which isn't called (on purpose), so the question is what modification needs to be made to make it compile. Can it just be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `undefined` optional:

```
// the semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated
// scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.
; (function ($ : any, window, document, undefined?) {

// undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
// mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
// passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
// can no longer be modified.
```

This will allow the template to compile since undefined is not passed into the function.